# File in assets folder needs a resId to be used

Tags: android, soundpool

I am new to Android, so this is probably a dumb question.

I have a sound file in my assets folder:

```
app|assets|www|sounds|hooray.ogg
```

Now I want to load it into my SoundPool

```
// THIS IS NOT RIGHT and is underlined in wavy error-red
mySoundPool.load(m_Context,
                "file:///android_asset/www/sounds/hooray.ogg",
                1);
```

It is saying the "file:///android..." etc should be a resId.

**How do I assign a resId to this file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I assign a resId to this file?

You can't. A resource ID is for resources, not assets.

Either:

- Move this file to `app/src/main/res/raw/hooray.ogg` and then use `R.raw.hooray` as your resource ID, or
- Use `getAssets().openFd("www/sounds/hooray.ogg")` to get an `AssetFileDescriptor`, then pass that to [a different version of the `load()` method on your `SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor,%20int))

Comment: I have the R recognised, but the raw in r.raw.hooray is underlined in wavy red. I have manually created the raw directory in my desktop file system. How do I let android studio know I have this raw directory? It is appearing in the file structure in Android Studio, but obviously it is underlined in wavy red.

Comment: @Rewind: If the directory is appearing in Android Studio, then Android Studio knows about the directory. To try to get the `R` class to create `R.raw`, clean your project (Build > Clean Project) and see if that helps. If the file in the project tree is marked with a wavy red line, then Android Studio and the build system do not like something about the file, such as illegal characters in the filename.